# gnome applications wont start in Fluxbox desktop in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10, gtk, fluxbox

I have been using Fluxbox the lightweight window manager and desktop environment instead of Unity for a while since my openGL applications need all the GPU juice they can get .

Since upgrading to 13.10 , I cannot start any Gnome applications inside Fluxbox.

They all fail with the message complaining about libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

```
hari@hari-Precision-WorkStation-T7500:~$ gedit
gedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: atk_text_get_string_at_offset
```

I have all the atk components installed as shown here:

```
hari@hari-Precision-WorkStation-T7500:~$ dpkg --list | grep "atk"
ii  gir1.2-atk-1.0                                2.10.0-2                                   amd64        ATK accessibility toolkit (GObject introspection)
ii  libatk-adaptor:amd64                          2.10.2-1ubuntu1~saucy1                     amd64        AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge
ii  libatk-adaptor-data                           2.10.0-1                                   all          AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge - transitional dummy package
ii  libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64                      2.10.0-1                                   amd64        AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge - shared library
ii  libatk1.0-0:amd64                             2.10.0-2                                   amd64        ATK accessibility toolkit
ii  libatk1.0-0:i386                              2.10.0-2                                   i386         ATK accessibility toolkit
ii  libatk1.0-data                                2.10.0-2                                   all          Common files for the ATK accessibility toolkit
ii  libatk1.0-dbg:amd64                           2.10.0-2                                   amd64        ATK libraries and debugging symbols
ii  libatk1.0-dev                                 2.10.0-2                                   amd64        Development files for the ATK accessibility toolkit
ii  libatkmm-1.6-1:amd64                          2.22.7-2                                   amd64        C++ wrappers for ATK accessibility toolkit (shared libraries)
```

Please can someone tell me how I can get libatk compatability to allow Fluxbox to launch gnome applications: which worked seamlessly till 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get gnome applications to start again by adding /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu where the 
libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0.0.0 was to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
That fixed the error I was seeing and allowed me to launch gnome applications in Fluxbox.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```